# Volume of the solid: $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:\ x^2+y^2 \le 4; 0 \le z \le x^2+y^2+4\}$

Tags: integration, volume, solid-geometry

I am trying to calculate the volume of the solid from the following restrictions using double integral:

$$S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:\ x^2+y^2 \le 4; 0 \le z \le x^2+y^2+4\}$$

From this I then graphed the following regions:

$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=16 \rightarrow \text{Ellipsoid} \\
x^2+y^2=4y \rightarrow  \text{Paraboloid}
$$

After graphing the regions and determining the desired section, I am not sure how to proceed especially in changing to polar coordinates.

Comment: Use the standard switch to polar coordinates: $x=\rho\cos\phi, y=\rho\sin\phi $.

Comment: @user8734617 and the $z$ variable?

Comment: z stays z, if you want a triple integral, but I assumed you would calculate it as a double integral (as a 'volume under a surface').

Comment: Therefore I integrate the function of $z=\sqrt{16-r^2}$?

Comment: $z=r^2+4$, I would assume...

Comment: @user8734617 How did you come about that?

Comment: From the original problem formulation:  $0\le z\le x^2+y^2+4=r^2+4$.

Comment: @user8734617 My mistake.

Comment: @user8734617 From what I understand so far, I am getting the following: $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^8{(r^2+4)}\ drd\theta$. Would that be correct?

Comment: Close but not right. What does $dxdy$ transform to? Why does $r$ go all the way up to 8? (What is the radius of the circle?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change to cylindrical coordinates. Your domain of integration is a circle in the plane $z = 0$ of radius $2$. How can you write that in polar coordinates? And for $0 \leq z \leq x^2 +y^2 + 4$, what's this in polar coordinates? Once you've figured that out then recalling the Jacobian factor we have,

$$\textbf{Volume} = \int_{\theta = ?}^{\theta = ?} \int_{r = ?}^{r=?} r \int_{z = 0}^{z = ?} \ 1 \ dz \ dr \ d\theta $$

[image]

Comment: What if I am to use double integral?

Comment: Just use $(x^2+y^2+4) - 0$ as the integrand then. I wrote it like that so it could be easy to point out where I'm getting that integrand from. I hope this helps.

Comment: Using the triple, would this be correct: $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^4r \int_0^{r^2+4}1\ dz\ dr\ d\theta$$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.